# How to share the Google APIs Console with other developers

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-api-console

I have hired a developer to host Wordpress site on the Google Cloud and App Engine. He is asking me to provide my password of Gmail account so that he can host it for, but I don't want to provide my password to access Google APIs console. Is there any way to give access to other developer to work, just like Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, if you go to the following URL you can add developers to the project:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/<application-id>/permissions
```

Answer (score 15):

1. Login to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/
2. Click on **top left menu** and
3. Go to **IAM & admin** >> **IAM**  >>  Here you can add/remove users and manage permissions.

Comment: even if I add new users in the IAM console, they are still not able to see the project :(

Answer (score 0):

The link where you can manage the permissions:

`https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=<your-project-id>`

If you do not have a project yet, create one here:

`https://console.developers.google.com/projectcreate`